# Postman, changing cookie values

Tags: api, cookies, postman

I am having issues with changing return authentication cookie values in postman. I have an environment variable called token and my initial login POST request contains these Tests:

```
if (postman.getResponseCookie("ccsrftoken")) {
tests["Login successfull"] = responseCode.code === 200;
var token = postman.getResponseCookie("ccsrftoken").value;
var clean_token = token.replace('"','').replace('"','');
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("token", clean_token);
```

After the request I can see that there is a cookie **ccsrftoken** available with following value:

```
ccsrftoken="34FDB4830CE5C33A54566B9BEDEE3B2"; path=/; domain=29.203.248.13; Expires=Tue Jan 19 2038 02:14:07 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time);
```

But the environment variable is set to

```
%2234FDB4830CE5C33A54566B9BEDEE3B2%22
```

Seems my replacement code does not work as expected and the " are still present in the string. I have also tried the replace("\"","") variant with same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you don't need to do any replacement actually.
I've been pulling JSESSIONID this way and when you use **.value**, it already pulls just the "34FDB4830CE5C33A54566B9BEDEE3B2" and skips the rest.

Comment: Hi Klubi, at the end I have changed the replace function slightly, instead of replacing the " character I changed that to %22 and now it working as expected.